# Using "the" before a nominalised adjective "small"

Tags: determiners

Instead of putting:

> You're a giant in the land of small people

could I say:

> You're a giant in the land of small

(referring to the Lilliputians in Gulliver's travels?)

Or should I use “the” before a nominalised adjective “small”:

> You're a giant in the land of **the** small

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should use the "the."

The lone adjective sounds like it should be followed by a noun. By adding "the" to it, you make it into a noun, effectively.